# How to change DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have would like to remove hours, minutes and second for a Date (dataType DatTime).

example from

```
28/02/2013 15:66:26
```

to

```
28/02/2013 00:00:00
```

I have tried using `AddMinutes`, and `AddHours`, but with no success.

Could you please provide me some pseudo code?

Comment: Using the `.Date` property like everyone else said is correct. Another thing to watch for though in general is that DateTime is immutable, so `AddHours` and such, will have no affect on the variable you do it to. It **returns** it's result. The proper way is probably `mydate = mydate.AddHours(1);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property:

```
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

Or

```
DateTime date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

if you don't like using `var`.

Comment: may I ask you... why do you use var?

Comment: @GibboK: Just simplicity. Either will work, and they'll compile to the same code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.Date` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) of the `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var mydate = DateTime.Now;
var date = mydate.Date.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get just the Date parts use

```
var myDate myDateTime.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime Structure has a property called Date. This exposes Date with time component being 00:00:00

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you are creating the date time
var newDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

//Another way to do it, just for seeing that it exists
var newDate = existingDate.Date + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it is:

```
date = 28/02/2013 15:66:26;
var date1 = date.Tostring("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If you further want to convert the type of date1 from String to DateTime then use

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
```